# Remote Desktop Connection (mstsc.exe) is having font issues for just some accounts

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, fonts

We have some contractors who are remoting into a development server using Remote Desktop Connection (`mstsc.exe`).  One or more of these contractors is reporting that when they remote in and run SQL Server Management Studio or Visual Studio, some of the fonts are messed up and it's interfering with their work.

I was able to reproduce this problem using a domain admin account.

Below are a couple of screenshots using mstsc, remoting into the development server on my regular domain account and then doing the same thing remoting in using the admin account.

Regular Account (fonts look okay):
[image: SSMS Signin dialog, logged in with regular account]
[image: SSMS Stored Procedure list, logged in with regular account]

Administrator Account (screwy fonts):
[image: SSMS Signin dialog, logged in with administrator account]
[image: SSMS Stored Procedure list, logged in with administrator account]

The server operating system is Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition. It is up-to-date on all patches, updates, etc.

The client operating system, running Remote Desktop Connection, is Windows 10 Enterprise.  It is also up-to-date on all updates.

Below is an image of the "Server Properties" dialog's "Advanced" tab when logged in with my admin account (it looks fine when viewing logged in with my regular domain account):
[image: Advanced Server Properties]

I could sure use a hand resolving this issue!

Thanks!

Comment: What options are you and your contractors using for the RDP connections (Options>Experience)?  Have you tried turning some or all of them off?  I've never had a problem with using only Visual styles and Persistent bitmap caching selected.

Comment: Which Windows versions for client and server? If you are using a .rdp file, please post it - I am principally interested in any options relating to the display.

Comment: @B540Glenn - Not sure what options they're using, but in all instances when I connect (both as admin and normal account), options are as follows:
Display: Full Screen

Comment: @B540Glenn - one more time -
Experience tab is set to "LAN (10Mbps or higher)" and the following are checked:
"Font smoothing", "Visual styles", "Persistent bitmap caching", as well as "Reconnect if the connection is dropped"  are all checked.  I've also tried unchecking "Font smoothing" and "Visual styles" together and separately, no joy.
For what it's worth, the display configuration is set as "Full Screen" and color depth is set to "Highest Quality (32 bit)".

Comment: @harrymc - the server is WIndows Server 2008 R2, the client is WIndows 10 Enterprise Edition, it has the update "Update for Windows 10 Version 1511 for x64-based Systems (KB3149135)" applied.

Comment: @harrymc - RDP file is posted here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0iZ4NkQuKXcZGVac1BpTUlGSms

Comment: .rdp tweaks that might help to know if they have any effect :(1) Delete `desktopwidth` and `desktopheight` (2) Turn on font smoothing (3) Set Connection type to auto. You may get better control over the options by using [Remote Desktop Connection Manager](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44989). To see if the problem is only with RDP try TeamViewer. Do you logoff from the server session before connecting? - Otherwise try to logoff, wait 2 minutes, then re-logon. Does this happen with Windows 7 client? Are client & server fully patched including video drivers?

Comment: It might be a Win 10 issue.  I tried to re-create the problem using your .rdp file from my Win 7 64-bit destop to a WIndows Server 2008 R2 and couldn't.  One other suggestion would be to change the font in SSMS for the admin account.  Does that have a similar problem?

Comment: @B540Glenn - I don't think it's an issue with Win 10.  If I login to the remote machine using my regular (non-admin) account there is no problem.  I can't find anyway to change the font used by SSMS.  I tried, but not able to with this version of SSMS (10.50.6220).

Comment: @harrymc - I've tried your suggestions of turning on font smoothing.  I also tried setting connection type to auto.  I've also tried the remote desktop connection manager, all to no avail.  When disconnecting from the server, I always logoff.  Client and server are both fully patched, including video drivers.  But I don't see how it could be a video driver... if I simply remote in with my standard (non-admin) account, the font issue goes away completely (which is also why I don't think this is an rdp client issue).

Comment: Maybe you should look at the server instead of the client. (1) On W2k8R2, Start->Administrative Tools->Remote Desktop Services->Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration, right click on the connection name and post a screenshot of Client Settings. (2) On W2k8R2 create another admin account and test it. (3) For Visual Studio : Try another font  than Consolas which always uses ClearType. The [Text Sharp](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7aafa2ea-8c54-4da8-922e-d26bf018514d/) extension can help in your testing.

Comment: (4) For admin, is there a registry entry for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\TrueType`. (5) Have a look also at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Font Mapping`. Compare registry settings with an account that works,

Comment: @harrymc - I ran the Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration.  It says that the server is configured for Remote Desktop for Administration, and that the Remote Desktop Session Host role service is not installed.  I'll post multiple images of the connection properties when connected with the non-admin account, which has no font issues, and the admin account, which exhibits the font issues.  See screenshots here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0iZ4NkQuKXcNFl1VklybjByVEU

Comment: @harrymc - I can't find either of the two registry entries you've pointed to when logged into either the admin or non-admin account.

Comment: No entries means no problems of that type. The screenshots you have sent seem identical for both accounts. Still left above : (2) and (3).

Comment: I feel like the coding problem for the administrator account, check this page to see if it works? [link](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2010/11/change-default-language-for-sql-server.html)

Comment: @SimonMC.Cheng - Thank you for your suggestions.  I've followed the advice in the link you provided and still no joy.  The account I have that experiences the problem shows the same results as for the account that does not have the problem.  I've modified my question to include a screenshot of the Advanced tab of SQL Server's server properties window

Comment: What happens if you logon directly at the server console with the affected account?

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT, @ Twisty I won't be able to test for another 12 or 13 hours.  Will get back to you then.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT, I've checked shortcuts and only the **Remote Desktop Connection Manager** offers the **Compatibility** tab.  It is already set to "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings".  **Remote Desktop Connection**'s shortcut does not offer that setting.

Comment: @Twisty, you had a GREAT suggestion to help troubleshoot this problem and I can't believe I didn't think to try it myself.  Logging onto the machine's console directly, bypassing **Remote Desktop Connection Manager** and **Remote Desktop Connection**, shows that the problem is limited to the server.  When I login with either the admin account or the non-admin account directly to the console, it behaves _exactly_ the same as it does when logging in over **RDCM** or **RDC**.  Therefore, this is definitely not an issue with remote access.  If you care to restate this as the answer...

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT, I think I must have misunderstood your first note.  I've now tried using new shortcuts for both products, and selecting "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings".  No joy.  They look identical as when using shortcuts that do not have that checkbox checked.

Comment: @STLDeveloper Glad we're making progress by eliminating Remote Desktop as the root cause.  Are you able to delete the Windows user profile for the affected account and create a new one to see if that solves the problem?

Comment: @Twisty, created new account with new profile - still see issue.  Attempting to duplicate working profile into new account.

Comment: @STLDeveloper If I understand correctly, the problem is affecting the admin account but not the non-admin account.  What happens if you temporarily grant the non-admin account administrative permissions? Sorry if this has been answered already in the comments. Since the bounty period is about to end I'm going to post my earlier answer at your invitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible the issue isn't specific to Remote Desktop.  The problem may be with the remote computer itself instead of Remote Desktop.  Examples include corruption of font files or in the settings of the user profile.

To test for this, log on to the computer directly using the affected and non-affected accounts and observe the results.  If the issue persists you've ruled out Remote Desktop as the cause.

Given some but not all of your user accounts are affected, you can narrow down the source of the problem by leveraging differences between the accounts in your testing.  Try a new user profile.  Try promoting the non-affected account to administrator status to determine if that's contributing to the symptoms.

You may find some clues by using Microsoft [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor). From the product description page:

> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity.

You can use Process Monitor's powerful filtering tools to find events that may be relevant to your problem.  I suggest you start by excluding all events that return a result of `SUCCESS` as shown here:

[image]

While there will still be a lot of events that (legitimately) fail, you may very well find some action that fails in some manner that has to do with loading or manipulating fonts.

Comment: I'm now certain that it has nothing to do with a connection over RDP.  I've tried a couple of things, such as having a new domain account created, as well as replicating a profile from the working account.  I still don't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was *not* with remote connections of any type.  Confirmed that the issue was noticed when logging directly into the server console.

I still have not found a real solution to this issue!